# Available RDS licenses but still no access

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

We have two Remote Desktop servers (Windows 2008 Server R2), with one of them being the license server. We had 30 CALs so only 30 sessions could be opened. We bought 5 more CALs and installed them on the license server. Licences seem to be installed and working but we cannot get more than 30 users at a time.
Licensing diagnosis throws no errors and shows the right number of licenses available (35).

I've looked into *RD session host configuration* and in the RDP-tcp connection properties, in the label: *Network Adapter* there is a Maximum connections option, set to 30, but is greyed out and I cannot change it.

Also I've tried to set the GPO in

```
[Computer_Config - Admin. template - Windows Components - Remote Desktop Services - Remote Desktop Session Host - Connections]
 -> Limit number of connections
```

to 999999. But still no access for more than 30 users.

Comment: This isn't a licensing problem. Where did you edit the Group Policy settings? In GPMC on a Domain Controller or in GPEDIT on the RDS server?

Comment: The GPO was modified on the RDS License server and also on the other RDS server, both through GPEDIT and both with no effect.

Comment: What error message do you get when attempting to connect the 31st user?  Are you able to connect an additional administrative RDP session at that time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was trying to set that GPO in the Local Group Policy for each RDS Server, once I set the same GPO on the Domain Controller (Domain Policy), it allowed me to have the connections that I want.